# Why files/folders are created with different ownership in docker run as root?

Tags: node.js, docker

Could you explain why this happens?

When I have such **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["touch", "somefile"]
```

I execute:

```
sudo docker build -t test1 .

sudo docker run -it --mount type=/my_folder,dst=/app test1
```

I get **somefile** created by **root** user.

When I have such **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["npm", "install"]
```

I execute(the same as above):

```
sudo docker build -t test1 .
sudo docker run -it --mount type=/my_folder,dst=/app test1
```

I get **node_modules** created by **non-root** user

Why do I get different users for created files in both cases? Isn't is supposed to be root user?

Comment: What happens when you don't mount `/my_folder`?